# Makefile base target and its dependent

Tags: makefile

I have a make structure like :

```
base : 
      build.sh base.output

//# if base.output is newer than sub-base.output by 1 minute then build the below -- How do i do this ?
sub-base : 
      build.sh sub-base.output
```

basically if a base folder/target changes all the dependent folders/targets need to be built.

I was thinking of writing a shell script to check the timestamp but makefile provide better way to do this?

Comment: Is the "1 minute" a specifically important number or is "newer" enough? Because "newer" is how make works. You just list the file that you want to compare against as a prerequisite of the target that depends on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what makefiles do. This is their purpose.

Just use the following as your makefile.

```
base.output:
      build.sh base.output

sub-base.output: base.output
      build.sh sub-base.output
```

Then running `make base.output` will run that recipe and `make sub-base.output` will run `build.sh sub-base.output` but only when `sub-base.output` is older than `base.output`.

You should list any prerequisites of `base.output` on its target line as well to get make to handle that correctly.

Or, if there aren't any, then you need to use a [force target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Force-Targets).

```
FORCE: ;

base.output: FORCE
        build.sh base.output
```

to force make to build `base.output` even when it already exists.

If you want to keep the ability to say `make base` or `make sub-base` then you need [phony targets](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) for those as well.

```
.PHONY: base sub-base
base: base.output
sub-base: sub-base.output
```

Comment: Thanks, How do i generate - sub-base.output: base.output
      build.sh sub-base.output             in auto tools ?

Comment: Not a clue. Presumably you need to list `base.output` as a source for `sub-base.output` but beyond that I don't know. Assuming you want to have the autotools do that generation part for you. You don't need to. You should just be able to embed that rule in the `.in`/`.am` directly and it should be put into the final makefile also I believe.